# No query results for user model when sending emails with Queue Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

In Laravel 5.8, there are no query results for Model App\Models\user when sending an email with queued notifications. When the notification is directly sent, there is no problem. But when I used jobs, I received an error about the User Model Not found.

**Controller**

```
$notifiables = User::all();

if (count($notifiables) > 0) {
    Notification::send($notifiables, new NewTrainingNotificationUser(Training::find($id)));
}
```

**Notification class**

```
class NewTrainingNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->from(env("MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS"), env('SMS_TOPIC'))
            ->subject("Nouvelle formation ajoutée.")
            ->greeting('Bonjour ' . $notifiable->lastname . ' ' . $notifiable->firstname . ',')
            ->line('La formation (' . $this->training->title . ') a été ajoutée pour votre équipe.')
            ->line("Team " . env('SMS_TOPIC'))
            ->salutation('Cordialement,');
    }
}
```

And here is the error I received in the failed_job table

````
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php(85): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->firstOrFail()
#1 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php(55): Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications->restoreModel(Object(Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier))
#2 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesModels.php(45): Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications->getRestoredPropertyValue(Object(Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications->__wakeup()
#4 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(42): unserialize('O:48:"Illuminat...')
#5 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(83): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#6 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(327): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#7 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(277): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#8 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(118): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#9 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#10 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#12 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#15 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(572): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#16 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#17 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#18 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#19 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(89): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /var/www/html/otd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /var/www/html/otd/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 {main}```

Please, has anyone encountered this error before?
````

Comment: In your User::class, is there `boot()` method? If so, can you provide the code?

Comment: Also, there is a misunderstanding. You fire the notification with an collection of users, but you code only handles one? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Hi, No, there is no boot method in my User::class. For the collection of users if I am not wrong you can fire a notification with a collection of users and use it like it is for one user. It w'ill be used for all the users

Comment: Ok, seems like in your user::class is "something" that cannot be serialized ... can you post the whole class (the whole user.php file)? In most cases, this is some custom attribute or something related to $with or $append

Answer (score 0):

Hi Paladin here is my whole user.php file

````
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

//use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    //use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    use SoftDeletes {
        restore as private restoreA;
    }
    use EntrustUserTrait {
        restore as private restoreB;
    }

    public function restore()
    {
        $this->restoreA();
        $this->restoreB();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    /*protected $fillable = [
        'slug',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'username',
        'email',
        'email_verified_at',
        'phone',
        'country_id',
        'password',
        'reset_password_token',
        'reset_password_token_end_at',
    ];*/

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'reset_password_token',
    ];

    /*
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model) {
            //dd($model->slug);
            $model->slug = str_slug('slug-' . $model->id);
            //$model->slug = uniqid().strtotime("now");
        });
    }
    */


    public function getQualifiedKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }


    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }


    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function fonction()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Fonction');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Media');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function messageUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MessageUser');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function trainingUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TrainingUser');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function evaluationUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EvaluationUser');
    }

    public function isOnline()
    {
        return Cache::has('user-is-online' . $this->id);
    }

    public function region(){
        return $this->hasOne(Region::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function getTeamTrainingsAttribute(){
        if (isset($this->attributes['team_id'])){
            return TrainingTeams::query()->where('team_id', '=', $this->attributes['team_id'])
                ->select('training_id')->get();
        }
        return [];
    }

    public function getNomComplet(){
        return $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname;
    }

    public function fullName(){
      return $this->getNomComplet();
    }
}```
````